# Regular Expression Javascript binary number validation

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to convert binary to decimal value

I am need a regular expression for validating the binary number.

```
//for now i am using 

var binary="1234"

 /^-{0,1}\d+$/g.test(binary)

//my output:

1
```

but i want the output to say not in binary format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should accept your recent questions

Comment: More to the point, accept *answers* to your questions (click the hollow checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most).

Answer (score 3):

```
/^-{0,1}\d+$/g.test(binary)
```

validates any positive or negative integer (`\d` means "any digit"; also `-{0,1}` can be written as `-?`). The `g` global flag doesn't make much sense here since you want to validate an entire string, not a substring in a longer, multi-line string (which wouldn't work anyway because the anchors `^` and `$` make sure of that already).

Try this instead:

```
/^[01]+$/.test(binary)
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: when i enter 1234 in my text box. the output is 1,but i must restrict this and show a alert saying not a binary format.

Comment: `/^[01]+$/.test("1234")` returns 0/False. What did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

That it matches every found entry and not just the first.

Comment: no it is taking the first number 1 and giving me the output.i must restrict this.

Answer (score 0):

```
/[^0-1]/g.test(binary)
```

In this way checks all characters that aren't 0 or 1.

Probably isn't the best way to do it, but it worked for me.

Comment: you created an inverse regex